# Как правильнее сделать такой функционал?

Tags: php

есть вот такое объявления

```
*31 Декабря с 8:00 до 17:00
1 Января выходной день
Со 2 января по 8 Января 10:00 до 23:00
9 Января с 11:00 до 23:00*
```

График работы ресторана
Вопрос как лучше сделать что бы в дни и часы что ресторан не работал переменная $classMain = 'not-worked'

В остальное время ресторан работает круглосуточно кроме с 6 до 8
И я делал тогда такое условия

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow'); 
  $simpleDate = date('Y-m-d');
  $nameDay = date('l', strtotime($simpleDate));
  $timeMoscow =  intval(date('H'));
 if($nameDay == 'Saturday' || $nameDay == 'Sunday') {
    if($timeMoscow == 6 && $timeMoscow == 7 || $timeMoscow  == 8 || $timeMoscow == 9){
      $classMain = 'not-worked';
    }
  }
```

НО делать по такой же аналогии очень долго и неправильно. Может как то поставить данные в объекты и массив и по нему проверять. у кого какие есть идеи) Буду очень рад за подсказки

Comment: а в остальные дни даже с 6 до 8 не закрывается?

Comment: Заголовок вопроса должен хоть как-то определять суть, не просто "Помогите", "У меня ошибка", "Как сделать такой функционал".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы сделал примерно так:

```
<?php
function working()
{
    // Время работы по определенным датам (сокращенные дни, праздники и т.п.)
    $time_work=array(
        array("2020-12-31 08:00:00","2020-12-31 17:00:00"),
        array("2021-01-02 10:00:00","2021-01-02 23:00:00"),
        array("2021-01-03 10:00:00","2021-01-02 23:00:00"),
        array("2021-01-04 10:00:00","2021-01-02 23:00:00"),
        array("2021-01-05 10:00:00","2021-01-02 23:00:00"),
        array("2021-01-06 10:00:00","2021-01-02 23:00:00"),
        array("2021-01-07 10:00:00","2021-01-02 23:00:00"),
        array("2021-01-08 10:00:00","2021-01-02 23:00:00"),
        array("2021-01-09 11:00:00","2021-01-02 23:00:00"),
    );
    // Нерабочие периоды на определенные даты (праздники, выходные и т.п.)
    $time_not_work=array(
        array("2021-01-01 00:00:00","2021-01-01 23:59:59"),
    );
    // Основной график работы, если время не попадает в одну из дат выше
    $time_work_regular=array(
        // Понедельник с 0 до 6 и с 8 до 0 и т.д.
        'Monday'   =>array(["00:00:00","05:59:59"],["08:00:00","23:59:59"]),
        'Tuesday'  =>array(["00:00:00","05:59:59"],["08:00:00","23:59:59"]),
        'Wednesday'=>array(["00:00:00","05:59:59"],["08:00:00","23:59:59"]),
        'Thursday' =>array(["00:00:00","05:59:59"],["08:00:00","23:59:59"]),
        'Friday'   =>array(["00:00:00","05:59:59"],["08:00:00","23:59:59"]),
        'Saturday' =>array(["00:00:00","05:59:59"],["08:00:00","23:59:59"]),
        'Sunday'   =>array(["00:00:00","05:59:59"],["08:00:00","23:59:59"]),
    );
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow'); 
    $now_date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $now_time=date("H:i:s");
    $nameDay = date( "l" );
    // Проверяем на работу в определенные даты
    foreach ($time_work as $interval)
    {
        if (($now_date>=$interval[0]) and ($now_date<=$interval[1])) return true;
    }
    // Проверяем на нерабочие дни
    foreach ($time_not_work as $interval)
    {
        if (($now_date>=$interval[0]) and ($now_date<=$interval[1])) return false;
    }
    // Проверяем на работу по графику
    foreach ($time_work_regular[$nameDay] as $interval)
    {
        if (($now_time>=$interval[0]) and ($now_time<=$interval[1])) return true;
    }
    return false;    
}

$now_work=working();
if ($now_work) {echo 'работает';} else {echo 'закрыт';}
```

Т.е. три массива: 1. Рабочие дни выбивающиеся из основного графика (сокращенные, праздник) время начала периода, время окончания периода, 2. Отдельный массив на выходные дни (периоды)., 3. Основной график, там только дни недели и время начала и окончания (если есть перерыв, то 2 записи до перерыва и после)